# what is the password for downloading games?

Tags: permissions

I am trying to get a game called torcs and supertuxkart and it says to add or remove software the super user has to take the action and I have edubuntu.So what is the password?

Answer (score 6):

For administrative actions, such as installing new software or making changes to the system's configuration, the system asks you for **your user password**, the one you used to log in to the system.